# Making request jq to output memory and container

Tags: kubernetes, jq, metrics

how to make request to output coantainer name and how much memory and cpu usage.

```
\"container\":{\"memory\":{\"request\":{\"bytes\":6.142515354e+08}},\"name\":\"testcontainer\",\"cpu\":{\"request\":{\"cores\":0.3}}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  No real-world system is likely to produce the kind of gibberish you've shown as sample data, so it would probably be better to provide a more useful example. In any case, it is advisable to follow the [mcve] guidelines, both to ensure you get useful responses, and to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample input is a bit of a mess.  If you really have to deal with something like that, the best would be to modify the beginning and end of the string, to make it parseable as a JSON string:

```
"{ \"container\":{\"memory\":{\"request\":{\"bytes\":6.142515354e+08}},\"name\":\"testcontainer\",\"cpu\":{\"request\":{\"cores\":0.3}}}}"
```

Then you can run jq on it, e.g.:

```
< kubernetes.txt jq fromjson
```

yields:

```
{
  "container": {
    "memory": {
      "request": {
        "bytes": 614251535.4
      }
    },
    "name": "testcontainer",
    "cpu": {
      "request": {
        "cores": 0.3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now it's easy to write the queries to get the details you want, e.g.

< kubernetes.txt jq fromjson.container.memory.request

Comment: thank you so much! Sorry for mistakes, I recently stared to learn this.

Comment: can you pls explain what mean this symbol <

Comment: `< FILE CMD` is the same as `CMD < FILENAME` in bash and bash-like shells. But with jq you can also write jq FILTER FILENAME